# Creating inbox with news feed in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml

How would I go about creating a website where users can login, and get specific content from an xml service based on their membership details?

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to come up with the best solution.. my friend was suggesting I should simply use a database, or download data directly from dynamic text on the server which can be edited from the admin account (with a claim that some browsers or mobile browsers have problem with xml parsing in areas with connectivity issues). However, I thought I should ask since I don't have experience with neither. And this project is targeted for people with limited internet connectivity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the `FormsAuthentication` and `MembershipProvider` and `XmlDataSource` modules of ASP.NET. Google them, there are plenty of tutorials and help files.